# Yield a form on a different page using laravel

Tags: laravel, yield

I'm making a twitter look-a-like app.
I have a form to post a message on 1 blade (createMessage.blade.php) which is as followed:

```
@section('message')
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'message/postmessage']) !!}
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        {!! Form::label('body') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body', null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        {!! Form::submit('Post message', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection`
```

Now I want to get my form on different pages (such as my timeline) but if I try @yield('message') it doesn't work.

timeline:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @yield('message')
    //some code for my timeline
@endsection
```

I can't find out why it doens't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the form file should `@extends('timeline')` and timeline should extend the `@extends('layouts.app')`
but include is better

Comment: remove the @section('content') and @endsection thats in between @yield('message') on timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use 
`@include('createMessage.blade.php')` in the timeline file and remove the `@section` declaration in createMessage.blade.php